# Reduce and count documents based on previous values

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

Let's say I've got CouchDB documents in the following format:

```
...
{
  player: 'abcde',
  action: 'run'
},
{
  player: 'abcde',
  action: 'jump'
},
{
  player: 'abcde',
  action: 'left'
},
{
  player: 'abcde',
  action: 'right'
},
....
```

My `view` looks like this:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.player, doc.action)
}
```

How can I count how many times player `abcde` has an action `jump` **immediately followed by** action `run`? I don't want the total number of `jumps` and `runs`. It is even possible to access `previous` or `next` documents from the current one inside a `map` or `reduce` function?

Thank you!

Comment: No, your map function will have no concept of next, previous, or even the full collection. You can use try using a `_list` function to do those kinds of calculations.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately followed"? Are documents time ordered and you do not want `jump`, `right`, `run`?

Comment: @MarcinSkórzewski yep, that's what I want. AT:DominicBarnes thank's I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't access other documents in a map/reduce like that. For starters I don't think reduce order is explicitly defined, so 'previous' and 'next' aren't even really meaningful I'm afraid.

Instead I'd suggest you collapse the whole history of each players actions into a single document like:

```
{
  "player": "abcde",
  "actions" : [ "right", "run", "jump" ]
}
```

You can then count specific sets of ordered actions from the array in your map method alone, and trivially aggregate them as desired in your reduce.

Comment: Interesting approach. How would the `map` method look like?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/uHGgy/2/ for a running example. You can copy the mapFn() function from there directly in as a map method (without the 'var mapFn =' bit), and it should 'just work', no reduce necessary, unless you want to aggregate these results somehow.